# how to programmatically register an already setup bean to spring context

Tags: java, spring

I'm wondering how one can do that. Afaik there is BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface that let us use BeanDefinitionRegistry.registerBeanDefinition()  method before beans within context are initialized. That method accepts only a class / definition. But usually one needs to register a bean that is already set with properties. Otherwise the bean definition registration itself is kinda useless. I don't want to set it up additionally after I get it from context then.

When using singleton it's ok, but for prototypes I'd have to set the bean up for each getBean() .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the most preferable way of doing that was `GenericBeanDefinition` and `GenericBeanDefinition.setPropertyValues(MutablePropertyValues propertyValues)` and it's registering into an application context...